# How to concat some text in json exiting value

Tags: json, postgresql, updates

I have json like `"address":"Ghaziabad street no 2 near"` and I want to add some text.

After update I want

`"address":"Ghaziabad street no 2 near temple"`

```
create table address(details json)

insert into address 
values('{"ID":"001","name": "Ven", "Country": "Australia",  "city": "Sydney", "Job Title":"Database Consultant"}')
```

I have 300 records like that. My task is to concat some more text in city (key).

So the json like

```json
{
  "ID":"001",
  "name": "Ven", 
  "Country": "Australia",  
  "city": "Sydney alias meta ", 
  "Job Title":"Database Consultant"
}
```

I want to append alias meta in all rows json

Comment: Add full JSON example with table structure

Comment: Please add Complete JSON structure also.

Comment: Yes sure give me 10 min

Comment: create table address(add json)

Comment: append mote text as want at existing values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine `jsonb_set()` with the `->>` operator to get the old value. As you are using `json` rather than the recommended `jsonb` type, you need to cast the value:

```
update address
  set details = jsonb_set(details::jsonb, 
                          '{city}', 
                          to_jsonb((details ->> 'city')||' alias meta'))
;
```

`(details ->> 'city')||' alias meta'` gets the value of the key `city` and appends the string `' alias meta'`. This value is then used to set the new value for the `city` key in the `jsonb_set()` to update the column.

Comment: Thnku so much brother.